# Getting GtkTextView line number

Tags: gtk, gtk-textbuffer

How can I get a line number from `GtkTextBuffer` based on the current cursor position?
Let us assume that wrap-mode is set and I am in some where in middle of the 3rd line. But how can I get the program to tell me that I am in the 3rd line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because the text buffer doesn't know how big the user has resized the window. The best you can do is to use [`gtk_text_view_get_iter_location()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-get-iter-location) which gives you a rectangle of the pixel coordinates of an iterator.

You can divide the *y* coordinate by the height of the rectangle to estimate the line number, but of course that only works if all your lines are the same height.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old, still I'm answering to this.
To get the line number you can try the following
    `self.textview.get_iter_at_location(x, y).get_line()`
But I haven't tried this with wrap-mode.